# Antlr4: Confusing error message (concatenates correct and incorrect lines) for Java grammar

Tags: java, antlr4, grammar

I am trying to build my own parser based on the existing Java grammar.

Even if I use the Java7 grammar from [the source repo](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java), generate the parser and use the TestRig from antlr-4.9.3-complete.jar given the code:

```
1  public class Test {
2    public static void main() {
3      test
4      int b = 1;
5    }
6  }
```

I get the following error:

> line 4:8 no viable alternative at input 'test\n int'

So for some reason it concatenates the incorrect "**test**" line with correct "**int**" line.
Also it says "line 4:8" pointing at the "int" line when it should be pointing to "test" (line 3).

(In a regular Java editor I would see a correct error highlighting for the "test" word which would sound like):

> "Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration"

What do I do to arrive at a similar error with ANTLR so it only picks on the wrong "test" line?
Most likely it's just my misunderstanding how antlr interprets the errors, then how would I get the listener to at least report correctly the starting line?

Comment: Not an ANTLR user, but Java is not line-oriented.  Lines 3 and 4 are a single statement-or-declaration.   `test` might be just fine if followed by certain symbols ('=', '[', '(' for example).  You can't say it's wrong until you've processed the next line.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare a sophisticated editor/IDE with a parser (generated by ANTLR). A text editor/IDE knows more about the input source and can look up if `test` is a valid type, and give a meaningful error message if the type cannot be found.

ANTLR's parser rule "sees"  `test int b` as an `Identifier`, an `INT` and another `Identifier` token and cannot match any parser rule for these tokens, resulting in the error starting at the identifier `test`.

For example, if `class test {}` was in the classpath, then input without `int` would be valid:

```java
public class Test {
  public static void main() {
    test
    /*int*/ a = 1;
  }
}
```

It wouldn't compile of course, but the syntax would be correct:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Bart. Currently the syntaxError make it look like the problem starts from "int" as it gives me line 4. I would totally understand it if it gave me the start of test (line 3) so I could deal with the multiline "test \n int" construct.

Comment: Yes, because the Java grammar accepts `test` and then after it  "sees" `int` and then gives up: so it's the `int` where the error occurs. Like I showed in my answer: if you remove `int`, it parses just fine: so ANTLR thinks the `int` is the issue.

Comment: got it. So from that point on we can only rely on the tree and visitor/listener to take it further.